# Generar un archivo PDF a partir de un CLOB

Tags: oracle, plsql

Tengo un CLOB el cual contiene la respuesta de un webservice, estoy intentando generar un pdf con esa respuesta, antes funcionaba ya que la respuesta no sobrepasaba los 32767 caracteres y se almacenada en un varchar2 ahora me toco pasarlo a un clob, se me genera el pdf pero me sale es una codificacion no se que estoy haciendo mal, comparto el codigo.

```
l_temp    VARCHAR2(32767);
v_fh utl_file.file_type;
v_pos pls_integer := 1;
v_buffer raw(32767);
v_amount pls_integer := 32767;
--
BEGIN
--
l_nomFichero := p_num_poliza || '_' || p_num_docto || '_' || trn_k_lis.ext_mspool || '.pdf';
---
v_fh := utl_file.fopen(l_directorio, l_nomFichero, 'wb', 32767);
 --
 v_lob_len := dbms_lob.getlength(l_clob);
 --
 WHILE v_pos < v_lob_len 
 LOOP
    --
    DBMS_LOB.read(l_clob, v_amount, v_pos, l_temp);
    --
    l_raw    := UTL_ENCODE.base64_decode(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(l_temp));
    --
    utl_file.put_raw(file      => v_fh    ,
                     buffer    => l_raw,
                     autoflush => true   );
    --
    v_pos := v_pos + v_amount;
    --
 END LOOP;
 --
 utl_file.fclose(v_fh);
```

cuando se va a vizualizar el pdf se ve asi.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Un pdf lo debes guardar en un BLOB, de lo contrario tendrás que hacer una manipulación extra con una codificación adecuada como base64, por ejemplo.